# How to deal with nested subscriptions in Angular, when you might call a void method

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
this.rolesService.addEmployeeRoles(addDtos).subscribe(
            () => {
                if (removeIds.length > 0) {
                    this.rolesService.removeEmployeeRoles(removeIds).subscribe(
                        this.bsModalRef.hide,
                        error => console.log('error' + error));
                }
                else
                    this.bsModalRef.hide();
            },
            error => console.log('error' + error));
```

How can this be rewritten so I don't have to use nested subscriptions? I was looking at examples online, but I'm not sure how I would handle the `else` part here which calls a void method.

I have been looking at examples of `flatmap` I'm not sure how to apply them in this usecase.

Comment: I don't know your scenario, but why don't use [`exhaustMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/exhaustmap) from `rxjs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` or for example `switchMap`. As we we only need one inner subscription, I would go with `switchMap`. SwitchMap expects to an observable to be returned, you can just use `of` to create a dummy observable. I am not using `EMPTY` here as we want to perform a side effect after switchMap, i.e closing the modal. So I would suggest the following:

```ts
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'

//....

this.rolesService.addEmployeeRoles(addDtos).pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    if (removeIds.length > 0) {
       return this.rolesService.removeEmployeeRoles(removeIds)
    }
    return of('whatever');
  }),
  tap(_ => this.bsModalRef.hide())
).subscribe();
```

Alternatively you can return `EMPTY` when not making api call and close the modal inside subscribe.